# convert int to string then join another variable to create a full extension, then convert it to const_char*

Tags: c++

---

Getting this error when I try to get data from a variable to place it into the playsond function :

```
cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}

cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}

cannot convert 'LPSTR {aka char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'BOOL PlaySoundW(LPCWSTR, HMODULE, DWORD)'|invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'|
```

---

I have a c++ project that I'm working on to play sounds automatically selected from a random number between 1-5. I'm trying to change the variable from an int to string, then then to a const_char* then place a .wav extension on the file and place it into a function to auto play the random number.wav file.

Basically I want to create a var that's a string that can work to go this function:

```
PlaySound(TEXT(var), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

example of the function:

```
class carolTracks
{
    public:
        void track()
        {
            int num = 1;
            string tracknum = to_string(num);
            string tracknumext = ".wav";
            cout <<tracknum<<endl;
            cout <<tracknumext<<endl;

            //LPSTR chtracknum = (const_cast<char*>(tracknum.c_str()+tracknumext.c_str()));
            //PlaySound(TEXT(chtracknum), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        }
};
```

Comment: `tracknum.c_str()+tracknumext.c_str()` you are adding pointers there, not combining strings. Try `(tracknum + tracknumext).c_str();`

Comment: Even if you made the changes mentioned in the above comment, it seems you are using narrow strings when the function you're calling wants wide-character strings.

Comment: I'm new to c++. I'm more proficient in python.

Comment: MS api usually has 2 versions of functions that take strings. One that accepts `char *` and one that accepts `wchar_t *`. In this case you can call the non-unicode version explicitly with `PlaySoundA`.

Comment: @Adrian Both `std::string` and `std::wstring` are instantiations of the `std::basic_string` template with different underlying character types. They have the same interface.

Comment: @molbdnilo But does it return a char* or a wchar_t*? cppreference site just keeps pushing back to `basic_string::c_str()`!

Comment: @Adrian `basic_string::c_str` returns a pointer to the underlying character type, called `CharT` on cppreference.com.

Comment: Thanks for assisting... do you think there's a solution. I made changes to program now i'm getting this new error after I try to join both char together now it wont compile.               
 LPSTR chtracknum = (const_cast<char*>(tracknum + tracknumext).c_str());

Comment: invalid const_cast from type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to type 'char*'|

Comment: I'm stuck. any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `std::string`, which is based on `char`, but you are trying to use the `TCHAR`-based version of `PlaySound()` and are clearly compiling with `UNICODE` defined, so that `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` and `PlaySound()` maps to `PlaySoundW()`.  You are trying to use `char` data where `wchar_t` data is expected, that is exactly what the conversion errors are complaining about.

You are also misusing the string's `c_str()` method, as well as the `TEXT()` macro.

Just use `std::wstring` instead, and call `PlaySoundW()` directly, eg:

```cpp
class carolTracks
{
    public:
        void track()
        {
            int num = 1;
            std::wstring tracknum = std::to_wstring(num);
            std::wstring tracknumext = L".wav";
            std::wcout << tracknum << std::endl;
            std::wcout << tracknumext << std::endl;

            std::wstring filename = tracknum + tracknumext;
            PlaySoundW(filename.c_str(), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        }
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to continue using `std::string`, just call `PlaySoundA()` directly instead:

```cpp
class carolTracks
{
    public:
        void track()
        {
            int num = 1;
            std::string tracknum = std::to_string(num);
            std::string tracknumext = ".wav";
            std::cout << tracknum << std::endl;
            std::cout << tracknumext << std::endl;

            std::string filename = tracknum + tracknumext;
            PlaySoundA(filename.c_str(), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Just started to code in c++ 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

You are already advised to use wide version `wstring` (instead of narrow `string`) to be compatible with LPCWSTR params in PlaySoundW.
So your LPSTR chtracknum should be also wide and const to be compatible with `c_str()` from `wstring`, so you need `LPCWSTR chtracknum` (after you begin to use `wstring` instead of string)

Comment: here's what I'm doing and i'm still getting an error. I'm new to c++              LPCWSTR chtracknum = (const_cast<const*>(tracknum+tracknumext)wide.c_str());

Comment: i'm trying to find a way to switch from basic string(narrow) to wide string(wstring) then I should be able to use PlaySoundW(TEXT(var))

Comment: class carolTracks
{
    public:
        void track()
        {
            int num = 2;
            string tracknum = to_string(num);
            string tracknumext = ".wav";
            wstring wtracknum, wtracknumext;

            for (int i = 0; i <tracknum.length(); ++i)
                wtracknum += wchar_t(tracknum[i]);
            const wchar_t* chtracknum = (wtracknum+wtracknumext).c_str();
            PlaySoundW(TEXT(chtracknum), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        }
};

Comment: @ivonpint Such a loop is NOT the correct way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. Just use `std::wstring` by itself, you don't need `std::string` at all. Also, you can't use the `TEXT()` macro in this case, it only works with **literals**, not with **variables**. Also, `chtracknum` is a dangling pointer to invalid memory! Try this instead: `int num = 2; wstring filename = to_wstring(num) + L".wav"; PlaySoundW(file.c_str(), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);` See the answer I just posted demonstrating this.